# Horizontal Scroll Bar missing is some web apps

Tags: 2013, development

I have three web apps in a one WFE farm.

I have not fooled with any CSS or javascript or master pages.

In the first web app, the horizontal scroll bars work just fine.

In the other web apps, I don't have horizontal scroll bars anywhere.

And - if I move a content data base from the first web app (where there are scroll bars) and attach it one of the other web apps - the horizontal scroll bars disappear.

Can anyone help diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

The blame goes to a third party add-in.

I detached all the content databases, rebuilt the web app and reattached the content.

Everything was fine.

When I reactivated the third party add-in, the scroll bars disappeared again.

I'm not sure if the add-in messed the master pages or some scripts, but they've promised a fix!